# Getting error of including $, when it is not necessary

Tags: r

Hi all I have the following code in r:

```
$$ln(L(\lambda))=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i)(ln(\lambda))-n\lambda$$
```

when trying to knit the document I get an error that says:

[image]

I have never gotten this error before, any ideas?

Comment: If you have only the above code snippet in your `.Rmd`, does it still throw an error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... The code you provided doesn't have any errors,...

Comment: @MadyYuvi thank you, I was working on a server, it appears it had to do with the server,  I resorted to using \begin{align*}...\end{align*}

Comment: @Werner I had near identical code at other points on the doc and there was no problem in execution, I also retyped the code elsewhere and it worked. I think it was the server I was working on. using \begin{align*}...\end{align*} worked in the exact same spot

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be specific to my environment. The error went away once I put my code between

```
\begin{align*}
ln(L(\lambda))=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i)(ln(\lambda))-n\lambda
\end{align*}
```

This solution might not be the best for some users given that the output is centered, on the page which might not be desired by some users. It however outputted my code and avoided the error when knitting which was sufficient for me.

Comment: Since there's no alignment going on, you should use an `equation*` environment, *not* an `align*` environment.

Comment: `align*` is the wrong environment here. The error message in the question shows that tex was not in math mode at the point it reached `\lambda` presumably because of a mis-matched `$$` earlier (or because you are in inner horizontal mode where `$$` does not start math.  Note that `$$` should never be used in latex anyway.